# Filter agenda for all open TODO items and all DONE items from past 7 days

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I would like to use org-mode to facilitate weekly standups at work with people. I would like a workflow whereby I can filter the org agenda TODO list to only contain open all open TODO items in addition to DONE items that were marked DONE in the past 7 days.

I am aware of the archiving workflow but I would rather not have to archive things, just have them disappear from the agenda view after a period of time.

Is such a thing possible with a custom agenda view? I have been trying to do something with `log-mode` but have not been successful thus far.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `org-log-done` to `'time` then every time you mark an entry DONE it gets a `CLOSED` special property added.  You can search for these like other properties containing timestamps, for example `CLOSED>"<-7d>"` will find all entries whose `CLOSED` timestamp is in the last 7 days.  You can add an "or" condition to also list open `TODO` items: `TODO="TODO"|CLOSED>"<-7d>"` or you can just have multiple blocks in your custom agenda.